# Unable to compile due to Undefined Reference to Boost and Event Libraries?

Tags: boost, cross-compiling, linker-errors, libraries

When trying to compile bitcoin core using this following configure command, it does not work.

```
EVENT_PTHREADS_CFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu' EVENT_PTHREADS_LIBS='-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -levent' EVENT_CFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu' EVENT_LIBS='-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -levent'  CFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -levent -DBOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS -O1 -m32 -g -latomic -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -levent_core -lgcc_s --rtlib=compiler-rt' CXXFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -levent -DBOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS -O1 -m32 -g -latomic -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -levent_core -lgcc_s --rtlib=compiler-rt' ./configure --enable-static --disable-hardening --enable-util-cli --enable-util-tx --enable-util-wallet --with-libmultiprocess=no --with-incompatible-bdb --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

Here is the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-init.o): in function `directory_iterator':
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/directory.hpp:278: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, unsigned int, boost::system::error_code*)'
/usr/bin/ld: libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-init.o): in function `boost::filesystem::directory_entry::status() const':
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/directory.hpp:132: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::directory_entry::get_status(boost::system::error_code*) const'
/usr/bin/ld: libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-blockchain.o): in function `boost::filesystem::absolute(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&)':
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:258: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::absolute(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/usr/bin/ld: libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-torcontrol.o): in function `StartTorControl(CService)':
/home/blank/bitcoin-0.21.0/src/torcontrol.cpp:753: undefined reference to `evthread_use_pthreads'
/usr/bin/ld: libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-httpserver.o): in function `InitHTTPServer()':
/home/blank/bitcoin-0.21.0/src/httpserver.cpp:376: undefined reference to `evthread_use_pthreads'
/usr/bin/ld: libbitcoin_wallet.a(libbitcoin_wallet_a-walletutil.o): in function `recursive_directory_iterator':
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/directory.hpp:456: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::recursive_directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, unsigned int, boost::system::error_code*)'
/usr/bin/ld: libbitcoin_wallet.a(libbitcoin_wallet_a-walletutil.o): in function `boost::filesystem::directory_entry::symlink_status() const':
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/directory.hpp:134: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::directory_entry::get_symlink_status(boost::system::error_code*) const'
/usr/bin/ld: libbitcoin_wallet.a(libbitcoin_wallet_a-walletutil.o): in function `boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator::increment(boost::system::error_code&)':
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/directory.hpp:500: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::recursive_directory_iterator_increment(boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/usr/bin/ld: libbitcoin_wallet.a(libbitcoin_wallet_a-bdb.o): in function `boost::filesystem::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::copy_option::enum_type)':
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:355: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, unsigned int, boost::system::error_code*)'
```

I am trying to compile a 32bit version of the software on Ubuntu 20.04. I did some research and this problem might occur when the libraries are not for the right architecture. I double checked and I installed all libraries under the i386 tag. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it remotely readable:

```
export EVENT_PTHREADS_CFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu'
export EVENT_PTHREADS_LIBS='-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -levent'
export EVENT_CFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu'
export EVENT_LIBS='-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu;-levent'
export CFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu 
    -DBOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS 
    -O1 -m32 -g -latomic 
    -levent -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -levent_core -lgcc_s --rtlib=compiler-rt'
export CXXFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
    -DBOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
    -O1 -m32 -g -latomic
    -levent -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -levent_core -lgcc_s --rtlib=compiler-rt'

./configure \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-hardening \
    --enable-util-cli \
    --enable-util-tx \
    --enable-util-wallet \
    --with-libmultiprocess=no \
    --with-incompatible-bdb \
    --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

I do notice that

```
export EVENT_LIBS='-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu;-levent'
```

seems weird syntax. According to my quick scan, `${EVENT_LIBS}` is simply substituted in the command lines. The `;` doesn't separate options (it separates link directories at best). Instead use a space to increase the risk of it doing what you expect:

```
export EVENT_LIBS='-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -levent'
```

Of course, it would make even more sense to add the -L flag to LDFLAGS. The same would go for all `-l*` options that were added to `CXXFLAGS`/`CFLAGS`. I'm not sure whether bitcoin-core adheres to all automake conventions, but I'd expect a separation into `CPPFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, CXXFLAGS`and`LDFLAGS`:

```
export EVENT_PTHREADS_CFLAGS='-pthread'
export EVENT_CFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu'
export EVENT_LIBS='-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -levent'
export CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu 
    -DBOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS 
    -O1 -m32 -g
    --rtlib=compiler-rt'
export LDFLAGS='-latomic -levent -levent_core
    -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
    -lgcc_s'

./configure \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-hardening \
    --enable-util-cli \
    --enable-util-tx \
    --enable-util-wallet \
    --with-libmultiprocess=no \
    --with-incompatible-bdb \
    --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

**Disclaimer** I have not tried this.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips I will try this now and let you know

Comment: `ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, unsigned int, boost::system::error_code*)
>>> referenced by directory.hpp:278 (/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/directory.hpp:278)
>>>               lto.tmp:(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::directory_options))`

Comment: It would seem that Boost Filesystem isn't linking. Either that or it's the famous order of linker options problem. Did you move the `-lXYZ` flags to the `LDFLAGS`? Perhaps `-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` should be in LDFLAGS as well, just realizing.

Comment: Let me try that out, and I will let you know.